# Undefined symbols for architecture in Swift project

Tags: ios, xcode, frameworks

Anyone knows the cause of the error below? I already deleted the derived data, created a new project but still have the errors below. The files affected also are included in the "Compile Sources" section. Xcode is set to a custom derived data folder. This is what is set in the Framework Search Paths "../DerivedData/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator", "../DerivedData/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos" and "$(inherited)"

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:

_CGPointMake
_CGRectMake
_CGSizeMake
_UIEdgeInsetsMake
_dispatch_get_main_queue
```

I have project written in Swift and with some custom frameworks embedded.

Let me know if you have an idea what is the possible cause.

Answer (score 1):

Use `CGPoint(x: x_coord y: y_coord)` instead of `CGPointMake` and alike.
Are You calling `dispatch_get_main_queue()` with parentheses?

Comment: i didn't have this error before so what difference would it make?

Comment: I just realized I updated my Xcode to the latest(6.2). Could be the reason why it worked before until now. riodoro1 your suggestion pointed me to the the true cause and your suggestion worked.